# when page is re-opened, the content is not refreshed

Tags: php, html, http, redirect, header

When this page is opened, it will display the contents of a record in the textbox below:

[image]

After I edit the text and click on replace previous note with current:

[image]

The record is successfully stored in the database using this code in `ModifyNoteScript.php`:

```
$comment_update = mssql_query("UPDATE pmp_property__unit
    SET  
    comments = '$NOTE'
    WHERE 
    communityidy='$COMID' and
    unit='$UNIT'") 
             or die ("Changes to Record could not be Saved."); 

    if (!$comment_update)
    {
        $success=2;
    }
    else
    {
        $success=1;
    }


    header ('Location:ModifyNote.php?unit=' . $UNIT . '&COMID=' . $COMID . '&success=' . $success);
```

the `header` redirects the user back to the same page and this note is displayed:

[image]

the problems that i am experiencing is that:

1. the original note disappears in the textbox, and now the textbox is blank as you see above
2. if i click on `replace previous note with current` **AGAIN**, i get the same result as `#1` above, and in addition, what ever is in the textbox is **NOT** saved to the database.

here's the code for the page with the textbox (edit or delete the note):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="../nav/occupancypop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script type='text/JavaScript' src='../scw.js'></script></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function closewindow() {
parent.location = "occupancy2.php"
}

//-->
</script>

<body>
<div id="maincontentform">
<?php 

include '../Check.php';

  $success = $_GET['success'];
  if($success == 1)
  {
  echo '<span class="style4">*The note has been saved!</span><br />
    <br />'; 
  }
  elseif ($success==2)
  {
    echo '<span class="style4">*There was an error updating the note!</span><br />
    <br />';
  }



//GET the unit and community id
$UNIT = $_GET['unit'];
$COMID = $_GET['comid'];

include '../KiscoCustomConnect.php';

//Get the commnet
$Comment_Query = mssql_query("select top 1 comments from pmp_property__unit where communityidy='$COMID' and unit='$UNIT'");
if (mssql_num_rows($Comment_Query)>0)
{
$Comment=mssql_result($Comment_Query,0,'comments');
}
else
{
$Comment='';
}
?>

<span class="MainTitle">
 Edit or Delete the Note</span>
  <p><br />
  <table width="596" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="maintable">
    <tr class="odd">
      <td width="164"><div class="pickform">
        <ul>
          <li> 
            <div align="center">
              <p><strong><img src="../media/_space.gif" alt="" width="135" height="1" /><br />
                Update Notes</strong><br />
  <?php  echo 'for unit ' . $UNIT ?>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div></td>
      <td width="431">
        <form action="ModifyNoteScript.php" method="post"  />
        <input name="Comment" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Comment; ?>" />
        <input name="UNIT" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $UNIT; ?>" />
        <input name="COMID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $COMID; ?>" />
        <textarea name="Comment" cols="55" rows="6" class="text1" id="Comment"><?php echo $Comment; ?></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="sendnotify" class="formbutton" id="Submit" value="Replace previous note with current" />
      </form></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
  <blockquote>
    <p><br />

<?php      
  if($success == 3)
  {
 echo '<input type="button" name="Cancel3" class="formbutton2" id="Cancel3" value="Close" onclick="closewindow2();" />';
}
else
{
 echo '<input type="button" name="Cancel3" class="formbutton2" id="Cancel3" value="Close" onclick="closewindow();" />';
}
?>      <br />
      <br />
    </p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what am i doing wrong? I suspect it is something with `header`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i see happening is that you set in else case

```
else
{
   $Comment='';
}
```

the reason you getting into else case is below:

you use lower case to access **$_GET['comid']**, but when you set it its upper case **&COMID=**. I tried the following:

```
$arr['a'] = 'a';
echo $arr['A']; //echoes blank (false)
```

with your case:

```
$_GET['COMID'] = 'test';
var_dump($_GET['comid']); // results in undefined index comid
```

so i would change comid into upper case when trying to get the value.

Comment: thanks so much. i followed your advice. and i did do this $_GET['COMID'] = 'test'; and indeed it is returning 'test'! however this does not make sense, because when i look in the database, it does indeed have a value

Comment: What field type is COMID int or varchar

Comment: @kingdomcreation i did not specify! but in the DB it is an integer

Comment: You should then try to remove the quotes.

Comment: I posted another awnser... What about the unit is that an integer also

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some text in the $Comment='Test' so you would know when the mssql_num_rows returns  0 row

Answer (score 1):

```
 $comment_update = mssql_query("UPDATE pmp_property__unit
    SET  
    comments = '$NOTE'
    WHERE 
    communityidy=$COMID and
    unit='$UNIT'") 
             or die ("Changes to Record could not be Saved.");
```

Comment: after tracing the sql, i get select top 1 comments from pmp_property__unit where communityidy='40' and unit=''

Comment: so it looks like $UNIT does not get passed over succesfully from the header ('Location:ModifyNote.php?unit=' . $UNIT . '&COMID=' . $COMID . '&success=' . $success);